# handle back end error status in front end

Tags: reactjs, firebase, validation, authentication, error-handling

our back end developer send if email and password empty

```
{
    "errors": {
        "email": "please enter valid emails",
        "password": "please enter password"
    }
}
```

and if email and password not match with data base 
`general: "email or password not match"`

1st case he send data inside of object 2nd docent how can i handle this in front end ?

this my code for check textbox validations

```
exports.validateLoginData = (data) => {
      let errors = {};
      if (isEmpty(data.email)) errors.email = 'please enter valid emails';
      if (isEmpty(data.password)) errors.password = 'please enter password';
     return {
         errors,
         valid: Object.keys(errors).length === 0 ? true : false
     }
}
```

this is code for my login back end

```
exports.login = (req, res) => {
    const user = {
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    };

    const {valid,errors} = validateLoginData(user);
    if(!valid) return res.status(400).json({errors});

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
        .then((data) => {
            return data.user.getIdToken();
        })
        .then((token) => {
            return res.json({
                token
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            if (err.code === 'auth/wrong-password') {
                return res.status(403).json({
                    general: 'email or password not match'
                })
            } else {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    error: err.code
                })
            }

        })
}
```

this my login page js code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import AppIcon from '../images/icon.png'
//mivi stuff
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import  Typography  from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import axios from 'axios';

const styles = {
    form:{
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
    image:{
        margin: '20px auto 20px auto'
    },
    pagetitle:{
        margin: '10px auto 10px auto'
    }, 
    textfeild:{
        margin: '10px auto 10px auto'
    },
    button:{
        marginTop: 20
    },
    customerror:{
        color:'red',
        fontSize:'0.8rem'
    }
};




class login extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            loading: false,
            errors: {}
        }
    }
    handleChnage = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })
    }
    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        // console.log('hi');
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            loading: true
        });
        const userData = {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        }
        axios.post('/login', userData)
            .then((res) => {
                //console.log(res.data)
                this.setState({
                    loading: false
                });
                this.props.history.push('/');
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err.response.data)

                this.setState({
                    errors: err.response.data.errors,
                    loading: false
                })
            })
    }
    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        const { errors, loading,} = this.state;
        return (
            <Grid container className={classes.form}>
                <Grid item sm />
                <Grid item sm >
                    <img src={AppIcon} alt="app cion" className={classes.image} />
                    <Typography variant="h2" className={classes.pagetitle}>Login</Typography>
                    <form noValidate onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <TextField id="email" name="email" type="email" label="Email" className={classes.textfeild}
                            helperText={errors.email} error={errors.email ? true : false} value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChnage} fullWidth />
                        <TextField id="password" name="password" type="password" label="Password" className={classes.textfeild}
                            helperText={errors.password} error={errors.password ? true : false} value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChnage} fullWidth />
                        {errors.general &&(
                            <Typography variant="body2" className={classes.customerror}>
                                {errors.general}
                            </Typography>
                        )}
                        <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button}>Login </Button>
                    </form>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item sm />
            </Grid>
        )
    }
}

login.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default withStyles(styles)(login);
```

here when 
click login button with out enter email and password its show validation error

but email and password is empty and click login button its throw error

> TypeError: errors is undefined

```
 helperText={errors.email} error={errors.email ? true : false} value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChnage} fullWidth />
```

but in the console i log error status

`general: "email or password not match"`

my question is

`helperText={errors.email} error={errors.email ? true : false}` this is for only validation if its empty only it will show error but if any data enter and click login why this line got error

Comment: First time you are getting error which is correct behaviour, but second time after typing email and password also getting error?

Comment: yes if i enter email and password only i get error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood this correctly, then your situation is, component load for first time and without entering `email` and `password` you hit `login` button and as expected you get error.

But second time you enter `email` and `password` then you hit `login` button this time also you get error.

This is because you set state for errors first time when `email` and `password` fields are empty. Now when you type something then and hit `login` your previous state is as it is and in result you get error. You need to clear the error state before second hit.

You can clear error state before API call in `handleSubmit` function like,

```
let errors = {email:'',password:''} //define empty error state 
this.setState({
    loading: true,
    errors      //reset error state
});
```